# Is there a bug with the new version of Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I have installed the new version of Cytoscape V3.10.0. When I opened my saved .cys files, I do not see any networks in the "Network" panel (as shown below).

[image]

However, when I open the same file in an older version of Cytoscape V3.9.1, I see all the expected networks. At the same time, I see the "missing" networks in the "Show Grid" view.

Looks like I am missing a minor detail to see the networks through the "Network" panel, could you please advise?

Comment: Greetings.  If you run Cytoscape from the command line, do you see any backtraces or errors?

Comment: Dear @ScooterMorris, no, it's the same when I run it on the command line.